# Search API + Apache SOLR - No highlighted excerpts returned for stemmed terms

Tags: search

I have a **Drupal 7** site using the **Search API** and **Search API Apache SOLR** modules to provide search functionality to site visitors.

I'm running Apache SOLR 4.10.2 within my development Vagrant VM environment, and search results are returned for both stemmed and unstemmed terms which is great:

---

Example search term: **"car"**

Apache SOLR returns nodes with fields containing the text **"car"** and **"cars"**

---

The problem is, when Apache Solr returns nodes containing the stemmed term **"cars"**, no highlighted excerpts are returned. However results containing the exact term **"car"**  are returned with a hightlighted excerpt as expected.

After extensive searching I found this [blog post](https://www.finalist.nl/techblog/2015/06/improving-search-result-with-search-api-solr-better-search-excerpts/) which contains instructions on how to enable stemming for highlighted excerpts, but no luck.

Here is the excerpt of my **schema.xml** config file as per the instructions in the blog post:

```
<!--  Setup simple analysis for spell checking -->

 <fieldType name="textSpell" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
   <analyzer>
     <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
     <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
     <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="4" max="20" />
     <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
     <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
     <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
   </analyzer>
 </fieldType>
```

I have **restarted my VM** and **cleared and reindexed** all the nodes, but still no dice.

Has anyone else had this issue before?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that you, like me, had the "Highlight" filter enabled, which you shouldn't actually do for Solr. I found this nugget of info here:

https://www.drupal.org/node/2358065#comment-9319765

Though Solr returns the excerpt, that processor removes it if there's not an exact match.

Comment: awesome, thanks! will give this a go and post results

Answer (score 0):

In case someone using Drupal 8 sees this question (as I did), the advice to turn off the **Highlight** filter, which was correct for Drupal 7, is not the solution for Drupal 8. Instead:

- Edit your index at `admin/config/search/search-api`
- At the **Processors** tab, select the **Highlight** checkbox
- In the **Highlight** tab at the bottom of the page under **Processor settings**, select **Create excerpt**
- Save
- Edit your Solr Server at `admin/config/search/search-api`
- Open the **ADVANCED** section near the bottom of the page
- Select **Retrieve result data from Solr** and **Retrieve highlighted snippets**
- Save

Now you'll get highlighted snippets for stemmed words. No need to reindex.